# Where have my scientists gone?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I've been playing the game for a few hours and I have 2 missions to high-five scientists... but I never see any! I just get tumbleweed where there used to be scientists. What am I doing wrong? Do I just need to travel further?

Answer (score 12):

Go to the Stash and click gadgets. You may have the nerd Repellant active (which means they won't appear); turn it off and they should walk around from now on.

Comment: It's not *may have* - the tumbleweeds **only** appear if you have the repellent active

Answer (score 4):

You are using the Nerd Repellent. Removing scientists from the map is the whole point of that gadget.

Simply equip a different gadget from the Stash.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to solve, just unequip or replace the Nerd Repellent gadget.